# How to get coordinates of a moved/rotated shape in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, vector, 3d, rotation, translation

In order to perform picking in OpenGL, I need to cross the vector received by gluUnproject with the shape.
However as the shape has been rotated and translated, how can I get its new coordinates ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not trivial. You will have to intersect your shape with the ray. You can do this in several spaces:

I assume your Ray is in world space. If it is, you can transform the ray into object space with the inverse of the ObjectToWorld matrix (taking care to transform the normal correctly). Or, you transform your object into ViewSpace and do the calculations there.

Can you be more specific? Are we talking about an analytical shape, or a mesh?

Comment: I have a square, (0-0 -> 1000-1000) which I translate and rotate. My camera is not moving. I click on the square, unproject the result which gives me a ray. And I would like to know the coordinates of the intersection. I already have the code to do the intersection, but am missing the code to transform the object's coordinates in ViewSpace. Any help appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: If your camera is not moving, I assume you're not setting your view space matrix, so it's the identity Matrix?

In that case, the easiest would probably be to transform your square into world space. If your view matrix is the identity, your ray should already be in world space. You should already have this transform, it's the same as you're using to render the square.

Comment: Please don't use the word "space" for coordinate frames. That's something else entirely when talking about vector maths...

Comment: What's the correct terminology? worldFrame? worldCoordinates?